# Use an iMac with Thunderbolt as an external display

Tags: display, imac, thunderbolt, thunderbolt-display

I can't manage to connect my ***iMac (Retina 5K, 27-inch, 2017)*** Display with my  ***MacBook Pro (15-inch, 2018)***.

I have an Apple Thunderbolt 3 USB-C cable, both computer are on (logged with an admin user), but nothing happen when [I press Cmd-F2](https://support.apple.com/en-ie/guide/mac-help/mh30822/mac).

I tried to use AppleScript in case something was wrong with my keyboard, but same issue.

```
tell application "System Events"
    key code 122 using command down # Cmd-F2
end tell
```

Tried the other way round (from my MacBook Pro) same thing...

FY, I don't think this is an issue but both computer are in a different VLAN

*iMac : 10.15.4 (19E287), MacBook Pro 10.15.5 Beta (19F72f)* (pretty sure had the same issue when both was in 10.15.4)

Answer (score 0):

I should had read the KBase better .... [Use your iMac as a display](https://support.apple.com/en-ie/guide/mac-help/mh30822/mac)

> Note: Target Display Mode isn’t supported on iMac models with Retina
>   display. Only iMac (27-inch, Late 2009), iMac (27-inch, Mid 2010), and
>   iMac (Mid 2011 to Mid 2014) support Target Display Mode.